# Trying to evaluate nested variable names in Struts?

Tags: java, struts2

I am using struts 2 and am trying to do the following (creating dynamic variable names based on action properties and other variable values) :

Define the variables as follows :

```
<ps:set name="flag_${_actionProperty}"  value="class.property"/>
<ps:set name="flag2_%{#flag_${_actionProperty}}_${_actionProperty}" 
  value="class.property2"/>
```

I am trying to access the value of flag2 as follows but it doesn't seem to work, knowing that all the class (model) property values and action property values are not empty:

```
<ps:text name='%{#flag2_%{#flag_${_actionProperty}}_${_actionProperty}}'/>
```

Please advise what to do. Thank You.

In other words, how can I access a variable value which by definition depends on the value of another variable in the same scope :

This is variable 1, its name is "flag_" a certain action property that has a value, and is being assigned as a variable the value of a class property that is defined in the action and has a value.

```
 <ps:set name="flag_${_actionProperty}"  value="class.property"/>
```

We are safe till now.

Next I need to defined another variable flag2, the name of this variable is dynamic and is dependent on the value of the variable "flag_key"(assuming the ${_actionProperty} evaluates to "key" at runtime) so the name of variable 1 will be flag1_key. The second defined variable will the value of another class property in the action 'class.property2' but the name of this variable is dependent on the value of the first variable "flag_key".

Lets say the value of class.property is 'standard', so i expect the name of variable 2 to be "flag2_standard_key" where 'standard' is the value of the first variable and 'key' is the value of the action property. I need to assign the second variable a value of class.property2 "

```
 <ps:set name="flag2_%{#flag_${_actionProperty}}_${_actionProperty}" value="class.property2"/>
```

So what I am trying to do is to access the value of the second variable in the text tag, I need to evaluate the value of the first variable to obtain the name of the second variable, then in turn evaluate the value of the second variable with dynamic name to get the value of class.property2

```
<ps:text name='%{#flag2_%{#flag_${_actionProperty}}_${_actionProperty}}'/>
```

I understand that I use directly use the class property in the name of the second variable as follows :

```
<ps:text name='%{#flag2_${class.property}_${_actionProperty}}'/>
```

and i can get the value of variable 2 this way. But what if the name was built based on a value independent of the action? Is this doable in a way or another?

Comment: Struts tags doesn't allow to evaluate jsp el expressions

Comment: well it allows <ps:set name="certainFlag_${_pageRef}"  value="%{'true'}"/>
<ps:text name='%{#certainFlag_${_pageRef}}' />, but the problem is when we try to evaluate a variable name within a name.

Comment: It couldn't work *well*, `ps:` is non-standard prefix that could have different custom implementation, and of cause I didn't see it. You should post details :\\

Comment: Use OGNL. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to do a common complex business functionality using a single JSP file for the view that will show 2 different dynamically loading forms depending on the loading screen and some parameter definitions. I managed to solve this by directly accessing the action class property as follows : <ps:set name="flag2_${class.property}_${_actionProperty}" 
  value="class.property2"/>  and i could access it properly. I still believe the validity of the example I have first used where I need to dynamically build the variable name I am setting and it is a valid scenario, please try to understand it.

Comment: The tag lib I am using is just to have custom prefix, and doesn't affect in any way the data evaluation within the text tag, so this is not the problem. Noting that the OGNL is being used in this case for definition and obtaining values from value stack.

Comment: You are doing some odd things. But if you say that first set is working then you can create a second set with value of the first and so on...

Comment: Well that's true but the problem will be in the evaluation of the value of the second set, it never works... Anyway thanks for help I have managed to overcome this issue.